# Output class file for a class object created in Soot

Tags: java, soot

For a test generation task, I need to generate `.class` files programmatically. I'm using the Soot framework to generate the code. Let's say I've created a class through `Scene.v().makeSootClass("Test")` and added some methods to it. How can I now compile that virtual Java representation of the Soot IR structure down to an actual `.class` file?

The docs list some output options for their [command line interface](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/options/soot_options.htm#section_3), but I'd like to do this programmatically through an API in Java, and I cannot find instructions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a number of searches, I've found the appropriate [documentation](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Creating-a-class-from-scratch#write-to-class-file) explaining to do this. The relevant code snippet from those docs is this one:

```
String fileName = SourceLocator.v().getFileNameFor(sClass, Options.output_format_class);
OutputStream streamOut = new JasminOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
PrintWriter writerOut = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(streamOut));

JasminClass jasminClass = new soot.jimple.JasminClass(sClass);
jasminClass.print(writerOut);
writerOut.flush();
streamOut.close();
```